# Synonym with categories with channel-categories with category

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The three versions of "Categories" need to be linked with each other.

[image: Category tags]

If possible all questions tagged with "category" or "channel-categories" should either have "categories" added as a tag or have those two existing tags replace by "categories"

Comment: Note: I am quite happy to do all the re-tagging but I wanted to hear the thoughts of others before proposing the synonym because quite franky there should not be three tags for "Categories" and it was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good suggestion - just merged these now and created synonyms as well.

Comment: Thanks Derek. Should "category-group" be added in as well?

Comment: That's a good question - you could argue that issues using category groups might be treated as distinct, but I don't know - maybe that's too granular?